# Reactでinput type="text"のvalueをボタンを押すことでリセットしたい。

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Reactでテキストフォームをリセットする方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか。
下記は動作デモです。
[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-moon-22s6f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

テキストフォームに「ok」を入力し「check」ボタンを押すことで"ok"というアラートが表示されます。
テキストフォームに「ok」以外を入力し「check」ボタンを押した場合は、"no"というアラートが表示されます。

デモにおいて、「clear」ボタンを押すことで、テキストフォームをクリア（空に）したいです。

### ソースコード

```js
import React from "react";

let text = "";

const App = () => {
  const inputValue = e => {
    text = e.target.value;
  };

  const check = () => {
    if (text === "ok") {
      alert("ok");
      return;
    }
    alert("no");
  };
  const clear = () => {
    text = "";
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" onChange={inputValue} />
      <p>please type "ok".</p>
      <button onClick={clear}>clear</button>
      <button onClick={check}>check</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

### 試したこと

テキストフォームのvalueをstateとして管理すれば、テキストフォームの中をクリアすることできました。
[demo2](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-euclid-d0s8v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

しかし上記のデモだとテキストフォームの文字が変わる度にsetStateされ、そのたびにコンポーネントがレンダリングされます。
できるだけ不要なレンダリングは避けたいです。

Comment: 思いつきなのですが、clearボタンが押されたかどうかをisClear=falseとしてstateに保持。clearが押されたらtrueに変えてレンダリング時にtrueであればtextを空にし、isClear=falseに戻す、なんていうのはどうでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。いただきましたコメントの方法ですと、useStateの宣言の前にisClearのbooleanを判定することになるかと思いますが、宣言前にstateオブジェクトを使おうとすると、'isClear' was used before it was defined. (no-use-before-define)というエラーが表示されます。 なにか勘違いしていたらすみません。

Comment: class componenの場合だとstateを使用してレンダリング時に操作することができるのですが，function componentだとFaily Feelyさんの仰る方法が良いかもしれません．お役に立てずすみませんでした．

Comment: 現在のhooksだとclass componentでできたことがいくらかできない、痒い所に手が届かない、といったことがありそうですね。私が全く扱いきれていないだけで、やろうと思えばできるのかもしれませんが。ご助言いただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この場合に一般的な方法は、input要素のDOMオブジェクトを取得して直に操作する方法です。変更箇所にコメントを付けてあります。

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

let text = "";

const App = () => {
  // input要素のDOMオブジェクトを入れておく用のrefを作成
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const inputValue = e => {
    text = e.target.value;
  };

  const check = () => {
    if (text === "ok") {
      alert("ok");
      return;
    }
    alert("no");
  };
  const clear = () => {
    text = "";
    // input要素のDOMオブジェクトを操作してテキストエリアをクリアする
    inputRef.current.value = "";
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* input要素にrefを渡すことでDOMオブジェクトを取得する */}
      <input ref={inputRef} type="text" onChange={inputValue} />
      <p>please type "ok".</p>
      <button onClick={clear}>clear</button>
      <button onClick={check}>check</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

stateに頼らずにテキストエリアをクリアしたい場合には、[input要素のDOMオブジェクト](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)を直接操作する必要があります（具体的には、input要素のDOMオブジェクトの`value`プロパティを`""`とする）。

そのために、上記のコードではinput要素のDOMオブジェクトを取得する処理を追加しました。これは、`useRef`を用いてrefオブジェクトを作成し、input要素のref属性でそのrefオブジェクトを渡すことで行なっています。Reactの機能により、こうすることで`App`コンポーネントのレンダリング後に`inputRef.current`にそのinput要素のDOMオブジェクトが入っています。

---

なお、このようにDOMオブジェクトを直接操作する行為は、このinput要素が**制御されたコンポーネント** (controlled component) である場合は行なってはいけません。
制御されたコンポーネントとは、`value`がstateとして管理されているコンポーネントのことです。この場合はstateを通じてクリアするのが正しい方法です。

今回はinput要素が制御されたコンポーネントではないので、この方法を行なっても構いません。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうござました。おかげさまで実装できました。